# Disable TinyMCE Table formatting width/height

Tags: tinymce, formatting, html-editor

Hi there I want to disable automatic formatting of table/td/tr widths and heights in WordPress TinyMCE.

I create the table, literally type the data in (not copying it from word or anything like that) and it adds in width and heights to my table cells. Then I copy the code into a text editor and remove the widths and heights, then paste it back in and it adds the widths and heights again.

Its giving me a headache. The table is responsive using bootstrap classes so no need for widths and heights.

If I want widths and heights I will manually put them there.

How to disable this??

Comment: tinyMCE is not exhibiting this behavior for me. Are you using a plugin such as tinyMCE Advanced or some kind of table plugin? The only way I'm able to get tinyMCE to add width and height attributes to the table markup is if I enter the HTML in the text editor, then switch to the Visual editor and drag the handles on the table to resize it.

Comment: Yes I am using tinyMCE Advanced - does this exhibit this behaviour? Thx

Comment: Sorry, I don't use it. I just had a hunch that you were :) Questions on third party plugins and themes are off topic here on WPSE, but you can try you luck over on the plugin's support forums: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/tinymce-advanced

Comment: I disabled this plugin as a solution

Answer (score 0):

The general recommendation seems to be to [downgrade TinyMCE Advanced to version 4.6.7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/advanced/#download-previous-link). I just did this myself and it solved the problem.

I needed to clean up the HTML of the affected tables by hand though.

There's [a topic on the plugin's support page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unwanted-inline-styles-added-to-tables/) with some other suggestions.